# How does for loops and elif work with python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

the following code:

```
df ['weight'] = 1
for feature in df.fclass:
    if feature == 'bus_stop':
        df.weight = 150
    elif feature == 'taxi':
        df.weight = 100
    else:
        df.weight = 50  
df.head()
```

results in the following dataframe:

[image]

I expected that the value of the 'weight' column to be 100 in the second column because df.fclass == taxi. Is there something wrong with the for loop or with my 'elif' request?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just setting values for specific rows (i.e. rows where `fclass` is equal to the feature), you are setting the whole column (`df.weight`) with the value. Given that the last feature of `df.class` is probably `bus_stop`, which has a `weight` of 150 based on your logic, the final output will have a `weight` column filled with only values of 150.

There are multiple ways of getting to the output you want: (1) you can use `.apply` with a function containing the logic you want, (2) use the `.loc` method to set values for just the rows you want (so just the rows where the `fclass` column has a specific value) in combination with a loop, or even better, (3) use `numpy.where`/`numpy.select` to set all values at once without looping over the different features.

```
# method 1
def weight_function(row):
    if row["fclass"] == "bus_stop":
        return 150
    elif row["fclass"] == "taxi":
        return 100
    else:
        return 50
        
df["weight"] = df.apply(weight_function, axis=1)

# method 2
for feature in df["fclass"].unique():
    if feature == "bus_stop":
        df.loc[df["fclass"] == feature, "weight"] = 150
    elif feature == "taxi":
        df.loc[df["fclass"] == feature, "weight"] = 100
    else:
        df.loc[df["fclass"] == feature, "weight"] = 50
        
# method 3
import numpy as np

conditions = [df["fclass"] == "bus_stop", df["fclass"] == "taxi", ~df["fclass"].isin(["bus_stop", "taxi"])]
choices = [150, 100, 50]
df["weight"] = np.select(conditions, choices)
```